# Managing two different versions of Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, rcp

Is it possible to have two version of the same plugin and load one or another on demand during runtime programatically? If yes, how?

Comment: I believe you can have multiple versions, but only if the plugin doesn't use extension points - [explained here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/165715/)

Comment: As much as I know, only if it is a plug-in without a `plugin.xml` file (which means that in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file there is no `singleton:=true`).

Comment: Thank you for your help